# Chrome with Linux-based OS

Tags: help

since my Chrome [chromebook] OS is a Linux-based operating system, why cant i install tor? i'm technologically challenged so please be gentle.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome [chromebook] is a surveillance/tracking device made by Google. You can't use it without Google account. You are the product for the ad industry. Exactly opposite what's Tor's mission.

Answer (score 0):

Chromebooks don't natively support the Tor browser.

Alternatively you can either run [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/index.en.html) in live or install another Linux distro via dual boot.

Comment: Tails wont work, since it just runs on amd64!